# Android Date Picker showing unwanted view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, datepicker, datetimepicker

```
val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
                        this@AddTaskActivity,
                        R.style.DateTimePickerTheme,
                        startDatePickerListener,
                        myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                )
    <style name="DateTimePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_blue</item>
    </style>
```

above is my code , view showing as above image 1.
but expected as below image 2.
there is Unwanted date is top of the date picker

Image 1 (Showing)
[image: Image 1]

Image 2 (Expected Image)
[image: Image 2]

Comment: KIndly let me know why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove title bar. To Remove title bar.. use this code

```
datePickerDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

**And Don't call datePickerDialog.setTitle("title")**

Remove setTitle if you use

```
datePickerDialog.setTitle("title")
```

Comment: I have added above line , its not worked. any other findings ? , its android 6 vivo v5

Comment: @bala did you use setTitle()?

Comment: After add datePickerDialog.setTitle("") , it worked fine